# Google Page Insights Image Links

Tags: pagespeed-insights

It looks like I can't get the image links to optimize my sites like I could in the previous version. Is there a way to get these links?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide more info, because your questing is not clear at all

Comment: I don't miss this feature at all in particular, because "optimized" versions it offered were always of inferior quality to originals (visual differences), same effect you could achieve by lowering jpeg or png quality in Photoshop. It was labeled as "lossless" but it wasn't. Better image compression can be achieved in Photoshop or some specialized software. Also, about lowering resolution, well, in responsive design you flip the phone to landscape mode and your 300x300 "optimized" image now sucks. You need to change your html as well to include src-set. It wasn't that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ben i am having the same issues, what he is talking about is before page insights was with lighthouse as it is now, we were given the exact resource needed in the form google requested them to be. So if we had an image that was 4 mb and 2000x2000 but the view port of where the image was lets say 300x300, google would provide that picture in a zip folder along with all other photos in the same boat. Also if javascript or css needed minification it also provided those files for us. I do not see that option at all any longer and its really disapponintng as it saved me two steps of optimiaztion in regards to page speed and hoping we can get it back!?

Comment: Thanks Rosario for explaining what I meant. That is exactly what I was talking about. It is disappointing that there isn't a way to retrieve these zip folders anymore. Let's hope Google will change it back!